# Draw svg path with mousemove in Angular

Tags: angular, svg, mouseevent

Am trying to draw svg path by moving the mouse using Angular, but am unable to accomplish this, idea is to draw path by following the mouse. How do I accomplish this in Angular? I am unable to target my svg element in order to start drawing the path. below is my component code,

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.svgPath = this.dataContainer.nativeElement;
};


handleMove(ev){
  svgPath =  createSvgElement("path");
  svgPath.setAttribute("fill", "none");
  svgPath.setAttribute("shape-rendering", "geometricPrecision");
  svgPath.setAttribute("stroke-linejoin", "round");
  svgPath.setAttribute("stroke", "#000000");
  svgPath.setAttribute("d", "M" + ev.clientX  + "," + ev.clientY);

 }
```

ant the template is:

```
<ion-content no-bounce>
  <div id="dataContainer" #dataContainer></div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think SVG (being vector graphics) is not the best suit for drawing following the mouse as you would have to define "paths" as checkpoints and also deal with whether its a straight line or curve or bezier curve etc. 
But you can probably do the following:

1. Create SVG with SVGPath element, whose d param is sort of empty = "M"
2. Properly detect mouse position (do matrix inverse trick to ensure you can capture where mouse is in SVG coordinates, you can see code in this snippet: [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/cmer41k/pen/vWXory?editors=1010)):

```js
mouse.x = event.clientX;
mouse.y = event.clientY;
mouse = mouse.matrixTransform(mainSVG.getScreenCTM().inverse());
```

3. On mousedown for example "add" new point to the path, on mousemove - move the next point-candidate around (if its a straight line and you decide to "draw" polygonal lines)
4. On certain other event like pressnhold etc - release "drawing" mode.

But to do specifics you need really to decide on what exactly you want to draw (like curves vs lines etc) as again vectors need directions (points through which you draw lines).

Otherwise your best solution would be html canvas bitmap drawing.